# Unpivot group of columns in SPARK SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I have a table structure like this:

[image]

Using SparkSQL, I would like to unpivot these columns into rows to produce the output like this:

[image]

So far, two achieve this, I have written two queries one for A and one for B as below:

```
select ID, Rank, Criteria  from (
SELECT *
    FROM Temp_Test_Hardik
  UNPIVOT( Rank for Criteria IN (
    A1,
    A2,
    A3
  )))
```

AND

```
select ID, Rank, Criteria  from (
SELECT *
    FROM Temp_Test_Hardik
  UNPIVOT( Rank for Criteria IN (
    B1,
    B2,
    B3
  )))
```

And then perform join between these two queries.

I would like to know that is there any better option to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better way. Create a array of structs of (A, B) pairs then use `inline` to explode the array into rows and columns

```sql
SELECT 
    PK, 
    inline(array(
        struct(A1 AS A, B1 AS B), 
        struct(A2 AS A, B2 AS B), 
        struct(A3 AS A, B3 AS B)
    ))
FROM Temp_Test_Hardik
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. Just one question, if I have large tables, is this better approach considering performance in mind ?

Comment: I guess this should be more efficient considering we are avoiding `join` which is a costly operation

Answer (score 0):

Please find below solution.

```
SELECT
  PK,
  inline(
    array(
      named_struct(
        'Rank', 1, 
        'A', A1, 
        'B', B1
      ), 
      named_struct(
        'Rank', 2, 
        'A', A2, 
        'B', B2
      ), 
      named_struct(
        'Rank', 3, 
        'A', A3, 
        'B', B3
      )
    )
  )
FROM source
```

```
+---+----+----+----+
|PK |Rank|A   |B   |
+---+----+----+----+
|1  |1   |A1-1|B1-1|
|1  |2   |A2-1|B2-1|
|1  |3   |A3-1|B3-1|
|2  |1   |A1-2|B1-2|
|2  |2   |A2-2|B2-2|
|2  |3   |A3-2|B3-2|
+---+----+----+----+
```